# Passing an unknown length of options to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.x

here is my existing (non-functional) code.

```
def call_GM(sourcefile):
    source = os.path.splitext(sourcefile)
    outfile = '"' + source[0] + '_straightened' + source[1] + '"'
    options = ('convert', '-auto-orient', sourcefile, outfile)
    command = 'gm'
    subprocess.call([command, options])
```

How do I correctly pass the contents of "options" given its length in not always fixed? This is the simplest example but I actually have similar code calling several different commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass command as flat list or tuple:

```
def call_GM(sourcefile):
    source = os.path.splitext(sourcefile)
    outfile = '"' + source[0] + '_straightened' + source[1] + '"'
    options = ['convert', '-auto-orient', sourcefile, outfile]
    command = 'gm'
    subprocess.call([command] + options)
```

NOTE: modified `options` to be a list because `list + tuple` is not allowed.